# Issues with vbox guest additions

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

I'm very new to both ubuntu and vbox so i apologize in advance for any things that are super obvious. im running ubuntu 16.04 ive got vbox5 running kali linux the latest version. It runs fine my issue is when i try to enable the guest whatevers so i can share a clipboard and everything else. i go to devices and click "insert guest additions cd image" and i get an error. 
"unable to insert the virtual optical disk /home/peter/.config/VirtualBox/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.0.40.iso into the machine, would you like ti try to force the insertion. I have searched for a fix for about two hours and have found nothing so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to shut down the virtual machine
2. Load the Guest Additions CD
3. Start the machine again
4. Through terminal go to that Guest Additions cd
5. Run this command in terminal when you are there

   `./VBoxLinuxAdditions`